# ROS2 on windows for controlling robot

Tags: ros2, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a project which is to use ros2 on windows 10 to control a ur5 robot.
Is there anyone know how to do this? or any resource on that ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301434/ros2-on-windows-for-controlling-robot/) by [kasumiwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37142/kasumiwen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
Is the project's goal specifically to use Windows 10 to control the robot, or ROS to control it? What dictates the Windows 10 choice?

**Comment by [kasumiwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37142/kasumiwen/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thanks for answering, the goal is to use ros2 on windows to control robot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have a look at https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control
This uses ROS 2 and has all the things setup for Windows as well (i.e. visibility macros etc). I used it for controlling an ABB robot with it. I believe with a correct hardware interface towards the UR5, you should be able to reuse some of the code.

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kasumiwen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37142/kasumiwen/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thank you for answering!
That is very helpful, I'll try that out!